# ImageView annoying behaviour in updated Android Studio (2.2.x) layout designer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, imageview

Every time in layout design view, after I drag the ImageView somewhere into my layout, "Resources" picker pops up. I can't dismiss it without picking any drawable, so I am forced to either pick something at random or not use the layout designer with ImageView at all.

[image: It drives me nuts]

It drives me nuts! I did not have this "feature" (or had it turned off) in previous versions of Android Studio. Does anyone know how to turn it off?

Comment: Interesting. Confirmed that with Android Studio 2.2.2. I agree, that's annoying.

Comment: Instead of selecting drawable select any color below of drawable option and click OK. It's not right solution, though :)

Comment: yeah, it is a workaround I use for now, but it really breaks the flow and slows me down... Tried to look up anything in the settings or poke around the new designer, but with no avail.

Comment: It's unbelievable, after about 2 years it's still the same. Just asked the same question without seeing this, and saw your question now, and it's still not fixed.